# Simple way to replace elements with certain attributes in php

Tags: php

How is it possible to get an element with a certain attribute?
Afterwards I want to replace this element including the tags of the HTML document within PHP?

I tried it here:

```
$html = '<note>
<span data="getThisElement">New Text</span>
<div  data="yes">More Text</div>
</note>';

echo$newTxt = str_replace("<? data="getThisElement", "<div>New Div</div>", $html);
```

The output should be:

```
<note>
<div>New Div</div>
<div  data="yes">More Text</div>
</note>
```

Comment: You should do that in javascript. You can find element using data attribute and then set `innerhtml` whatever you want. If you want to do in php, then use regex to `preg_replace`

Comment: Do not parse/alter HTML with regexps

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I can see that trying to parse HTML with regexps could be extremely complex, but is there some other reason for not doing it?

Comment: @JitendraYadav has a good point - JavaScript is already setup to parse HTML correctly..

Comment: @AHaworth regexps are unaware of what HTML is and how it is structured etc, while tools dedicated to parsing and manipulating are the way to go because you only need to care on **what** you want to do, not **how**.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski agreed,I raised JS because it is built to parse HTML whereas as you say regexps have no intrinsic idea. Of course if you have a good specialist tool to do it on PHP that's fine, but I didn't want to have to load new code - especially if I didn't know exactly how it worked - hence I'll use the JS route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with this

```
  $html = '<note>
          <span data="getThisElement">New Text</span>
          <div data="yes">More Text</div>
          </note>';
          
  $replace = "<div>New Div</div>";
  $output = preg_replace("/<span[^>]*>.*?<\/span>/is",$replace,$html);

  echo $output;
```

or if you want to replace it by specific element

```
$element = "getThisElement";
$output = str_replace('<span data=" ' . $element . ' ">New Text</span>',$replace,$html);
```

Comment: This shows using a preg_replace which could be a way forward for the problem but it is replacing all span elements rather than replacing all elements that have certain attributes like in the question (the attribute given was data="getThisElement").

Comment: @AHaworth 
Thanks for the hint. preg_replace looks better. 
However it does not look that it goes for a certain data element [^>]*? Where can I find a good explaination for the regular expressions?

Comment: I think you'd be better off either using one of the specialist PHP HTML parsers mentioned in the other answers or use the JS method in my answer. You will have a difficult time trying to write a comprehensive HTML parser from scratch.

Comment: MDN is usually a reliable source of information [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp but there are of course many tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest more advanced technique like **[Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)**. Here is your example:

```
<?php

include "simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php";

$html = '<note>
<span data="getThisElement">New Text</span>
<div  data="yes">More Text</div>
</note>';

// Create DOM from string
$dom = str_get_html($html);

$dom->find('span[data=getThisElement]', 0)->outertext = '<div>New Div</div>';
echo $dom;

// <note>
// <div>New Div</div>
// <div  data="yes">More Text</div>
// </note>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get PHP to echo some JS as well as the HTML. This can do the replacements for you as JS is good at parsing HTML and you don't have to add extra functionality to PHP. The result is the same. For more generality you could make the JS a function so can be used elsewhere echoed by the PHP if required.

```
<?php
$html = '<note>
<span data="getThisElement">New Text</span>
<div  data="yes">More Text</div>
</note>';
$repAttr = 'data="getThisElement"';// The attribute of those elements we want to replace
$repWith = '<div>New Div</div>'; // what we want to replace those elements with
?>
<div id="temp">
<script>

let el = document.createElement( 'div' );
let replaceWith = "<div>New Div</div>";
el.innerHTML = `<?php echo $html; ?>`; //note the use of backticks so the string can span many lines

let elsToReplace = el.querySelectorAll( "note"[<?php echo $repAttr; ?>]  ); // gets all the elements within $html that have the given attribute

elsToReplace.forEach(function (repEl) {
  repEl.outerHTML = '<?php echo $repWith; ?>';
});

document.getElementById("temp").outerHTML = el.innerHTML; //this will overwrite all this setting-up JS so the DOM will have the content required and nothing else

</script>
</div>
```